# Use limit in sub query

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables

- product
- status
- orders
- orders_products.

Using following query I get the proper result but it is not in correct order i.e. result gets by sub query.I want result order as sub query result.

```
SELECT 
    p.products_id, p.products_image, p.products_tax_class_id,
    pd.products_name, if(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price,
    p.products_price) as products_price 
FROM
    products p LEFT JOIN specials s
        ON p.products_id = s.products_id, products_description pd 
WHERE
    p.products_status = '1' 
    AND p.products_id = pd.products_id 
    AND pd.language_id = '2' 
    AND p.products_id in (
        SELECT * from (
            SELECT
                distinct(op.products_id) 
            FROM
                orders_products op,orders o 
            WHERE
                op.orders_id=o.orders_id 
                AND o.customers_id='27' 
            ORDER BY
                o.date_purchased 
            DESC LIMIT 0,10 
        ) AS temptable
    )
```

Comment: Why are you not doing an `INNER JOIN` with `products_description pd`?

Answer (score 0):

The outer SELECT has an ORDER BY pd.products_name. That's what should apply, and only that.

The sub-query ORDER BY shouldn't actually matter. You should get the same result removing it.

If you want a different sort order from pd.products_name, you have to ORDER BY the column required. In your case, you need to move orders.date_purchased to the main part of the query so you can use it to sort. Inverting the query, i.e. starting with what you want and relating everything else:

```
    SELECT MAX(o.date_purchased) AS date_purchased, DISTINCT (op.products_id) AS products_id
    p.products_id, p.products_image, p.products_tax_class_id, p.products_price
    pd.products_name,
    IF (s.status, s.specials_new_product_price, p.products_price) AS products_price

    FROM orders o

    LEFT JOIN orders_products op USING (orders_id)
    LEFT JOIN products p USING (products_id)
    LEFT JOIN products_description pd USING (products_id)
    LEFT JOIN specials s USING (products_id)
    WHERE o.customers_id = '27'
    AND p.products_status = 1
    AND pd.language_id = 2
```

Comment: how to use orders.date_purchased in main part of query

Comment: It's not that clear from your code what you are looking for, it seems though that you are looking for the 10 most recent product purchases. Inverting the query might help - I'll add it to my answer above.

Comment: Above query gives only one record if I remove MAX(o.date_purchased) it gives result but some rows are repeated.Thanks for response

Comment: Sorry, since I don't have a database to test it against, I can't be sure. I would try two things: remove the MAX so that it reads **SELECT o.date_purchased, DISTINCT ...** or try adding a **GROUP BY** at the end:

GROUP BY products_id, products_image, products_tax_class_id, products_price, products_name

Comment: Great, glad to help. Accept the answer if you're happy.